# Telerik RadFileExplorer And Server side codes

Tags: sql-server-2008, file, telerik, server-side, explorer

i have a file explorer like below :

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="SearchBar.aspx.cs" Inherits="FileExplorer.SearchBar" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" TagPrefix="telerik" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
//        function OnClientFileOpen(oExplorer, args) {
//            args.set_cancel(true);
//            radopen(args.get_item().get_url());
//        }

        function OnClientFileOpen(oExplorer, args) {
            var item = args.get_item();
            var fileExtension = item.get_extension();

            var fileDownloadMode = document.getElementById("chkbxDownoaldFile").checked;
            if ((fileDownloadMode == true) && (fileExtension == "jpg" || fileExtension == "gif")) {// Download the file
                // File is a image document, do not open a new window
                args.set_cancel(true);

                // Tell browser to open file directly
                var requestImage = "Handler.ashx?path=" + item.get_url();
                document.location = requestImage;
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <telerik:RadWindowManager ID="RadWindowManager1" runat="server">
        </telerik:RadWindowManager>
        <telerik:RadFileExplorer runat="server" ID="RadFileExplorer1" Height="400px" Hidth="600px"
            EnableCreateNewFolder="false" EnableCopy="true" OnClientFileOpen="OnClientFileOpen" enableopenfile="true">
            <Configuration ViewPaths="~/Files" UploadPaths="~/Files" DeletePaths="~/Files" />
        </telerik:RadFileExplorer>
        <br />
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkbxDownoaldFile" runat="server" Text="Open images for direct download " />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

the upper codes are just an example and you can see their demo in the below link ...
[FileExplorer / Filter files and download](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/fileexplorer/examples/applicationscenarios/filteranddownloadfiles/defaultcs.aspx)

i want to allow my users to download any file from my server without any preview (just save as window)...
so for this purpose i can change the upper codes easily.

but there is a situation here -> i want to capture and filter downloads (file size limit) (sql server 2008 database).
it seems RadFileExplorer only has client side events for my purpose!
when my page loads , i want to show RadFileExplorer to my user for just seeing it's files without any permission for download.
when he/she double clicks on a file i tell that user plz login first!
after his/her logined , he/she can download files but only 1 GB per day. 
how can i do this stuff for my RadFileExplorer ?
is web service and web methodes a good idea for this situation?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you are using relies on a handler - "Handler.ashx". All files are streamed using this handler so you can implement your server side restrictions in its code. I think you can also use the handler to redirect the browser to a different page if the user is not logged in.